# CPU load average + how to get cpu load average for history of 6 hours

Tags: linux, cpu, redhat-enterprise-linux, uptime

as all know we can get cpu load average as:

```
 uptime
 10:09:22 up 2 days,  1:44,  1 user,  load average: 20.01, 20.03, 22.05
```

but this show only

```
load average over the last 1 minute is 22.05
load average over the last 5 minute is 20.03
load average over the last 15 minute is 20.01
```

but we want list of load average for last 6 hours

any command that can show this?

Comment: This is unlikely, although you could likely set up an red database with a cronjob if you are desperate enough.

Comment: what we want is the CPU load average on each couple second in history of couple hours

Comment: logging that will significally INCREASE CPU load...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are the sysstat tools, they do logging and the with the sar tool you can query the logs for things like the cpu load during a specific time frame.
https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat